# Not the right result with Arithmetic Progression in C

Tags: c, math, integer-division, arithmetic-expressions

Im trying to sum the multiples of a number (x0) with a progression number (r) and a number of times (n). If I use the number x0 = 6, r = 3, n = 3, the result should be 
6+9+12=27, but the program gives me always 18.

I try different times changing the formula but if I do on the paper the result is right, so Im afraid the problem can be the syntax...

So theres the program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_progression(int x0, int r, int n)
{
  return (n/2) * ((2 * x0) + ((n - 1) * (r)));
}

void test_sum_progression(void)
{
  int x0;
  int r;
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &x0);
  scanf("%d", &r);
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int z = sum_progression(x0,r,n);
  printf("%d\n", z);
}

int main(void)
{
  test_sum_progression();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `printf("%d\n", (3/2));`.

Comment: Now let's leave him time to do that and learn, please.

Comment: I don't understand :/ Im new on C and some things are not to good to understand. Why I should print 3/2?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues: To get some insight into the root of your problem.

Comment: oh god i understand now :/ so to resolve I can use double right?

Comment: `return (2*x0 + ((n - 1)*r)) * n/2;`  (do the division by 2 last.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ints with division the value is calculated and then truncated to int.
if you divide int by int you should do something like:
    return (n/(double)2) * ((2 * x0) + ((n - 1) * (r)));

Comment: Bad idea to go to floating-point. Though with limited range, and only a single division by 2, it might work.

Comment: You are right. changed to double.

Comment: @atlanteh: `double` is also floating-point...

Comment: thanks people... sorry about my no vision :/ sometimes when we focus in something we can't see the most simple thing :/

Comment: Absolutely don't use floating point here

Comment: @atlanteh Using floating point numbers, like `float` or `double`, is really the wrong approach.  Think of a simple integer only solution.

Comment: How about return n * ((2 * x0) + ((n - 1) * (r)))/2; ?